# Machine Learning for optimizing parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

For my master's thesis I am using a 3rd party program (SExtractor) in addition to a python pipeline to work with astronomical image data. SExtractor takes a configuration file with numerous parameters as input, which influences (after some intermediate steps) the statistics of my data. I've already spent way too much time playing around with the parameters, so I've looked a little bit into machine learning and have gained a very basic understanding.

What I am wondering now is: Is it reasonable to use a machine learning algorithm to optimize the parameters of the SExtractor, when the only method to judge the performance or quality of the parameters is with the final statistics of the analysis run (which takes at least an hour on my machine) and there are more than 6 parameters which influence the statistics.

As an example, I have included 2 different versions of the statistics I am referring to, made from slightly different versions of Sextractor parameters. Red line in the left image is the median value of the standard deviation (as it should be). Blue line is the median of the standard deviation as I get them. The right images display the differences of the objects in the 2 data sets.

I know this is a very specific question, but as I am new to machine learning, I can't really judge if this is possible. So it would be great if someone could suggest me if this is a pointless endeavor and point me in the right.
 [image: Example 2][image: Example 1]

Comment: I think you should consider posting this question on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Comment: @Thomas, thank you for the tip. I didn't even know there was a forum like this.

Comment: Do you have a "ground truth" for the statistics you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can try an educated guess based on the data that you already have. You are trying to optimize the parameters such that the median of the standard deviation has the desired value. You could assume various models and try to estimate the parameters based on the model and the estimated data. But I think you should have a good understanding of machine learning to do so. With good I mean beyound an undergraduate course.